# Prove that if $T$ is self adjoint and $ T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive $k$, then $T(v) =0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T$ is self adjoint and $T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive $k$, then $T(v) = 0$.

The proof given is as follows:

Suppose that $T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive integer $k$. Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer with $T^m (v) = 0$. Let $2n$ be the least even number greater than or equal to $m$. Then $T^{2n}(v) = 0$ and $0 = \langle T^{2n}(v), v\rangle = \langle T^n(T^n(v)),v\rangle = \langle T^n(v),T^n(v)\rangle$. Then $T^n(v) = 0$ and it follows that $2n < m+2 \leq n+2$ which implies that $n<2$ and hence $m = n =1$. Therefore $T(v) =0$.

My question is why $m+2 \leq n+2$. Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: What do you mean by >=< ?

Comment: @HartoSaarinen: The $<\cdot,\cdot>$ stands for inner product.

Comment: inner product < . > the the equal sign is separate from the > and <

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, $m$ is the smallest positive integer with $T^m(v)=0$, and you have shown that $T^n(v)=0$. Therefore, $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because $m$ is the smallest integer such that $T^m(v) = 0$ and $n$ satisfies $T^n(v) = 0$. Therefore $m \leq n$.