# Let $V$ be an inner product space, $T$ a normal operator on $V$. Suppose $T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive integer k. Prove that $T(v) = 0.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be an inner product space, T a normal operator on V. Suppose $T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive integer k. Prove that T(v) = 0.

Proof given: Let $S = T^*\circ T$. Then S is self-adjoint and $S^k(v) = (T^*\circ T)^k(v) = (T^*)^k(T^k(v)) = 0$. Then $0 = S(v) = (T^*\circ T) (v)$. $0 = \langle v,T^*(T(v))\rangle = \langle T(v),T(v)\rangle$. Hence $T(v) = 0.$

My question is why $0 = S(v) = (T^*\circ T) (v)$? How is this result obtained?

Comment: You can use \langle and \rangle to denote the delimiters of the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $S^k=0$, $S$ self-adjoint your other question [Prove that if $T$ is self adjoint and $ T^k(v) = 0$ for some positive $k$, then $T(v) =0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043451/prove-that-if-t-is-self-adjoint-and-tkv-0-for-some-positive-k-then) implies $S=0$. Then for all $v$
$$
0=\langle Sv,v\rangle = \langle T^*Tv,v\rangle = \langle TV,Tv\rangle.
$$
Hence $Tv=0$ for all $v$, which implies $T=0$.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lemma:

**Lemma:** The only self adjoint operator $\;S\;$ that is nilpotent is the zero operator.

**Proof:** Suppose $\;s^n=0\;$ . We know there exists a basis (even an orthonormal one) for $\;V\;$ of eigenvectors $\;v_1,...,v_n\;$  of $\;S\;$ which correspond to **real** eigenvalues $\;\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\;$ (why and why?), and we also know that

$$Sv_k=\lambda_k v_k\implies\begin{cases} S^*v_k=\overline\lambda_kv_k=\lambda v_k\\{}\\S^mv_k=\lambda^mv_k\end{cases}\;\;,\;\;\;\forall\;1\le k\le n$$

Thus

$$S^m=0\implies\;\forall\;k=1,2...,n\;,\;\; S^mv_k=\lambda^kv_k=0\implies \lambda^k=0\implies\lambda_k=0\;\;\;\;\square$$